# AngularJS : wrong path in my url

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I use angularJs for my project with angular-route. I noticed that my project works very well but the url is never the good one. I mean I have this : **/app#/users/edit/78** instead of this : **/app/#/users/edit/78** I always saw url containing this : **/#/** I don't know why I have this mistake if somenone know how to fix this it's will be cool. Thx

Comment: did you setup a base url?

Comment: no I didn't setup a base url

Comment: @ExpertSystem: deep thoughts ... Bert: hard to guess where your mistake is. we need more code or you need to search your typo ;)

Comment: @nilsK: I do it with all my projects and it works every time !